# How to change the app icons of Linux Mint to defaults?

Tags: firefox, icons, mint, inkscape

The icons of Firefox, GIMP, Inkscape etc. are different. How to get back the original icons? Can it be done together (for all apps)?

Linux Mint icon:

[image: Linux Mint icon]

Original icon:

[image: original]

Comment: My friend : http://unix.stackexchange.com/ is best place.

Comment: we welcome here the official Ubuntu Flavors named as Ubuntu,Kubuntu,Xubuntu,Lubuntu,Ubuntu Studio. so any questions about them are welcome here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ubuntu tweak to restore the Icon set to system default icon set.

[click here to install](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/ubuntu-tweak) Ubuntu tweak in Ubuntu. After installing From Tweaks -> Themes you can do that.

Comment: I can't count the number of suggestions of installing Ubuntu tweaks, yet I can't count the number of hours I wasted because I followed them. Ubuntu tweaks can make your system unstable and can break it. This happened 3 times to me on 3 different computers over a period of 2-3 years. Now I will stay away from it. Use at your own risk.

Comment: @Morlock Do you have any suggestion without involving Ubuntu Tweak?

Comment: Live with the defaults and do not modify your system beyond what the normal settings permit. It is either this or be ready to break your system now and then and have to re-install it :(